# grunt-contrib-uglify keeps removing console.log

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I'm new to Grunt, trying to get `grunt-contrib-uglify` to work and it appears to be working well, however it keeps removing, `console.log('hello world')` every time it runs.

I see a lot of mentions on how to get Uglify to remove `console.log` but nothing on actually keeping, which I assumed was the default.

Here's my `uglify` task:

```
uglify:{
    options: {
        compress: {
            unused: false,
            drop_console: false
        }
    },
    my_target: {
        files: {
            '_/js/script.js' : ['_/components/js/*.js']
        } //files
    } //my_target
}, //uglify
```

Here's my JavaScript file:

```
function test(){
    return 'hello there again once more';
    console.log('test');
}
```

It's keeping the `return` line, but not `console.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test(){
    return 'hello there again once more';
    console.log('test'); <- this is at wrong place
}
```

it should be before return

```
function test(){
    console.log('test'); <- this SHOULD WORK
    return 'hello there again once more';

}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for pointing that out. Totally missed it. It's working now.

Comment: great! glad to help please accept the answer if it was helpful. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure it's actually removing it? Is it just that you aren't seeing the log in the console?

The `console.log` statement is *after* the `return` statement, so is never going to be executed. The function has stopped at that point. The try moving `console.log` to before the `return` statement.